# Two custom action bars

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to get two action bars in my application, like this:

[image]

Is it possible? If yes, how to implement it? It also must be working on Android 2.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible? If yes, how to implement it? It also must be working
>   on Android 2.x.

Yes this is possible. This is a normal `ActionBar` with a Spinner, a few Actions and an overflow icon(actually two, but you can only have one, so *that* might be almost impossible).
The `ActionBar` on the bottom is a [`split ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar).
You can use [`ActionBarSherlock`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Is it possible that top bar contain only one button? How to force set it?